# Questions about algorithms for permutation groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, algorithms, partitions, permutation-groups, computational-group-theory

Let $G < S_n$ be a permutation group of degree $n$, $\mathcal{P(n)}$
denote the set of all partitions of $n$, and $c: G \rightarrow
\mathcal{P}(n)$, where $c(g)$ is the partition given by the multiset of
cycle lengths of $g$.  Define the *profile* (is there a standard term
for this?) of $G$ to be the map $P: \mathcal{P}(n) \rightarrow
\mathbb{N} \cup \{0\}$ where $P(\pi) = \#\{g \in G: c(g) = \pi\}$ is the number of
elements of $G$ whose multiset of cycle lengths is $\pi$.

Question: Is there a pair of non-conjugate subgroups $G, H < S_n$
with the same profile?

In these questions I'm assuming that a subgroup $G < S_n$ is
specified by giving a list of generators.  When I ask for a "good"
algorithm I mean one that is subexhaustive.  Ideally it should run in
time polynomial in $n$.  For example, a lot of group theoretic
calculations have good algorithms using the Schreier-Sims algorithm
(and variants).

Question: Given a subgroup $G < S_n$ is there a good algorithm to
compute $P(\pi)$ for a given partition $\pi$?  It's easy to do this
"by hand" for $S_n$ and $A_n$.

Question: We are given a subgroup $G < S_n$, and $h \in S_n$, $h \not
\in G$.  For every partition $\pi \in \mathcal{P}(n)$, is there a good
algorithm which either determines that there is no $g \in h G$ with
$c(g) = \pi$, or if there is such a $g$, constructs one?

Added:
The motivation for this problem is the following: I was given pairs
$(h, G)$, where $h \in S_n$, and $G < S_n$ is a subgroup with $h \not \in G$.  I wanted to
find a $g \in G$ so that ${\tt cycles}(gh)$ was maximal among all
choices of $g \in G$, where ${\tt cycles}(g)$ means the number of
cycles in $g$ (including trivial ones).  I had thought of
exhausting over all partitions for this.  In some of the examples the
order of $G$ was small enough to exhaust over, but in others it was
huge.

Comment: For your first question the buzzword is "Gassmann triple" (you are in the special case where the ambiant group is $S_n$).

Answer (score 10):

The following is only an answer to the first question: Consider the subgroups $G_1=\langle (12)(34),(13)(24)\rangle$ and $G_2=\langle (12)(34),(34)(56)\rangle$ of $\Sigma_6$ which are both isomorphic to $C_2\times C_2$. They are nonconjugate (the first fixes $5$ and $6$, but the second moves all $6$ points) but they have the same profile (if I got the definition right): All elements except the identity have cycle type $(**)(**)(*)(*)$.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, is there an outer automorphism that takes $G_1$ to $G_2$?

Comment: No, any aútomorphism of $\Sigma_6$ sends $G_i$ to (a conjugate of) $G_i$.

Comment: And if you add one more (fixed) point to embed in $\Sigma_7$, there are no outer automorphisms to worry about.